# How to find the ComponentID of the component in MSI programmatically?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installscript-msi

Requirement is to delete few components during uninstallation programmatically. This also requires to delete the registry associated with the components . How to find the ComponentID of the component programmatically, in order to search in the registries .?

Comment: on which basis you want to search for component id? Do you have component name or anything?

Comment: Yes I do have the component name . Using component name is it possible to retrieve the component ID ?

Comment: Yes. You can easily retrieve component table.

Comment: Old components will be automatically removed on upgrade if you design your MSI correctly. You must not mess around in the MSI database in the registry. This can cause total corruption of your whole PC. There are cases when you have problems with old install that won't uninstall or upgrade due to runtime errors. In these cases [there are a few methods you can use to deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876981/129130).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve component table to fetch componentIds. Here is the installscript code:

```
    hDB = MsiGetActiveDatabase(hMSI);

// open view into Component table

MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDB, "SELECT 'ComponentId' FROM `Component` WHERE `Component`='<Component_name>'", hViewlist);

MsiViewExecute(hViewlist, NULL);
    
while (MsiViewFetch(hViewlist, hRecordlist) = ERROR_SUCCESS)
     
       //     perform your operations   
endwhile;
    
MsiViewClose(hViewlist);
```

Comment: Thank you @Vivek . This is the solution being looked for !