# The path cannot be found while uninstalling Java (TM) 6 Update 2

Tags: java, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I need to install a **Java 8** version. Earlier I had **Java 6 TM Update 2**, but now it's not in my computer (I've checked it on command prompt and nothing versions appeared). However, the folder with **jre1.6** is still here and in **add or remove programs** it is still found. When I click **uninstall** this appears

[image]

And when I submit (OK) this appears

[image]

The *jre1.6.0_02.msi* file might be deleted accidently. Whatever how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you done a global search for that .msi file? If you have and it's absent, you could always try to download it again.

Comment: You may try to delete the folder manually and follow [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1616076/646359) to get rid of the Java version from the list of installed software. If this fails, well, reinstalling Windows at least once in a decade is not bad. You may get rid of other legacy artifacts as a side effect.

Comment: For problems like these - broken MSI uninstalls - you should try the [Microsoft FixIt tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d). There is also the larger issue of [uninstalling your own MSI files that are broken during development work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876981/129130) (some approaches here can be used for all MSI uninstall problems, but the Microsoft FixIt solution is the best for most users). And [on MSI uninstall in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130)

Comment: g00se, I'm sorry for not answering. A long time I put off until the moment... The .msi file appears on global serach, but trying to dlete this it says it isn't here anymore. Also I found the archive of this jre on my computer. I suppose that I need to set the same path as the existing jre folder to replace the exisitng folders and files by the installing ones, isn`t it?

Comment: You never want to delete an msi file if you're trying to uninstall what it installs. Just forget about the old and install the new version